# How to rotate a normalized vector towards a point with joml

Tags: java, math

So this is my understanding of how to rotate a vector towards a point:

Vector A = (0, 0, -1)
Vector B = (15, 164, 16)

Step 1: Normalize B
Step 2: Calculate angle between A and normalized B
Step 3: Calculate the cross product of A and normalized B

Then, rotating A around the axis we calculated in step 3 by the angle calculated in step 2 (in radians) should give me the normalized vector of B.

However, trying to do it with joml i don't get the right result.
Here is my code:

```
Vector3f vecA = new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
System.out.println("Vector A: " + vecA.toString(FORMAT));
Vector3f vecB = new Vector3f(0, 0.5f, 1.0f).normalize();
System.out.println("Vector B: " + vecB.toString(FORMAT));

float angle = (float) Math.acos(vecA.dot(vecB));
System.out.println("Angle between the two: " + angle + "(" + Math.toDegrees(angle) + "°)");

Vector3f rotationAxis = new Vector3f();
vecA.cross(vecB, rotationAxis);

Vector3f rotatedVector = new Vector3f();
vecA.rotateAxis(angle, rotationAxis.x, rotationAxis.y, rotationAxis.z, rotatedVector).normalize();

System.out.println("Rotated Vector: " + rotatedVector.toString(FORMAT));
```

This results in the following output:

```
Vector A: (0 0 -1)
Vector B: (0 0.44721 0.89443)
Angle between the two: 2.6779451(153.43495411905388°)
Rotated Vector: (0 0.82566 0.56416)
```

From the calculation above, shouldn't the rotated vector be equal to the output of Vector B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to normalize your `rotationAxis`-vector since an axis is represented by a unit vector (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation).

Thus, simply replace

```
vecA.cross(vecB, rotationAxis);
```

with

```
vecA.cross(vecB, rotationAxis).normalize();
```

and it works:

```
Vector A: (0 0 -1)
Vector B: (0 0.44721 0.89443)
Angle between the two: 2.6779451(153.43495411905388°)
Rotated Vector: (0 0.44721 0.89443)
```